# Updating Post meta (ACF field) from Feed

Tags: loop

I'm trying to order my 'gyorshirek' posts based on the value of a custom field.
I'm getting the value of this field from a json field. I created a basic function that is supposed to update this field when WordPress loads, but for some reason it is not functioning properly.

```
function top_lista_valtozas(){

$args = array(
    'post_type' => 'gyorshirek', // Only get the posts
    'post_status' => 'publish', // Only the posts that are published
    'posts_per_page'   => -1 // Get every post
);
```

$posts = get_posts($args);

```
foreach ( $posts as $post ) {

    $ticker = get_the_title();
    $url = 'https://api.portfolio.hu/chart?ticker=' . $ticker ;
    $token = 'removed';
    $header = array(
        'headers' => array(
            'Authorization' => 'Bearer ' . $token,
            
        ),
    
        
    );
    
    $response = wp_remote_get($url, $header);
    $body     = wp_remote_retrieve_body( $response );
    $http_code = wp_remote_retrieve_response_code( $response );
    $formatted_json = json_decode($body, JSON_PRETTY_PRINT | JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE | JSON_UNESCAPED_SLASHES);


    
    
    if (isset($formatted_json['change_percent'])) {
    
    
        // Run a loop and update every meta data
        // update_post_meta( $post->ID, 'ceg_valtozas', $formatted_json['change_percent'] );
        update_field('ceg_valtozas', $formatted_json['change_percent']);
    }
}
```

}
// Hook into init action and run our function
add_action('init','top_lista_valtozas');

If I would have to give a wild guess, I would think that the issue was with the if statement, but I'm unsure as how to fix it. Any suggestions?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Realized that I did not need to make this into a function, and inside the template_part the
update_field('ceg_valtozas', $formatted_json['change_percent']);

did actually work, so some part of the code must have been undefined.